# Putting awk commands in a file

Tags: awk

I have the following `bash` call and want to put the `awk` commands in an `awk` file.  What I would like to do is put the specific functionality beginning from line `$0 ~ beg_ere {` and ending at line `display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }` in an `awk` function .  Then be able to call it from a `bash` function.

```
  awk -v ukeys="$keyw" -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v pn_ere="$pn_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere" \
    'function praggr (aggr) {
       resultstr = ""
       for (k in aggr) resultstr = (resultstr " | " aggr[k])
       return resultstr
     }
     $0 ~ beg_ere {
       title=gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0);
       subtitle=gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0);
       keywords=gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0);

       nu = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",");
       nk = split(keywords, kaggr, ",");

       display=0;
       if ( nu > 0 && nk > 0)
        {
         for (i in uaggr)
          {
            umatch=0;
            for (j in kaggr)
             {
               if (uaggr[i] == kaggr[j]) { umatch=1; break; }
             }
             if (umatch == 1) { display=1; }
          }
        }

       else if ( nu > 0 && nk == 0 )
        {
          display=0;
        }

       else if ( nu == 0 )
        {
          display=1;
        }

       if (verbiage)
        {
          print "Title: " title;
          print "Subtitle: " subtitle;
          print "Keywords: " keywords;
          print "uaggr: " praggr(uaggr);
          print "kaggr: " praggr(kaggr);
          print "nu:" nu;
          print "nk:" nk;
        }
       next
     }
     $0 ~ end_ere { display=0 ; print "" }
     display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
    ' "$filename"
```

Comment: You might want to fix the syntax error at line 38 first: `if ()`

Comment: I am not concerned about the syntax right now.

Comment: Please [stop posting large awk scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/734414/133219) and asking us to debug them for you. If you have a specific problem then create and post a minimal complete script that demonstrates just that problem. Chances are by doing so you'll solve the problem yourself. You need to be concerned about the syntax - posting a script that you know has a syntax error is just gives us things to consider that we shouldn't need to waste our time on and could stop us from being able to test or even pretty-print your code with `gawk -o-` to make it easier to read.

Comment: Please stop multi-posting (https://stackoverflow.com/q/75357599/1745001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I don't think it's possible to specify `awk -f` and `awk '{code...}'` simultaneously</s>.

In GNU awk (aka `gawk`) for reading multiple codes simultaneously you can use `-e` option, see `gawk --help` for more details. Also it'd be useful to read use `AWKPATH` (see `man gawk` to read about it).

To avoid using GNU awk in this case, you should specify multiple `-f` in `awk` command.

And *to avoid using two files* you can use **process substitution** `<(command)`.
For example, you can use -f `<(echo code ...)` for defining the function and inside an `awk` file you can define the other code, like this:

`test.awk:`

```c
{ // I'm not sure if the `{` and  `}` should be here or they're not necessary at all
 $0 ~ beg_ere {
       title=gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0);
       subtitle=gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0);
       keywords=gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0);

       nu = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",");
       nk = split(keywords, kaggr, ",");

       display=0;
       if ( nu > 0 && nk > 0)
        {
         for (i in uaggr)
          {
            umatch=0;
            for (j in kaggr)
             {
               if (uaggr[i] == kaggr[j]) { umatch=1; break; }
             }
             if (umatch == 1) { display=1; }
          }
        }

       else if ( nu > 0 && nk == 0 )
        {
          display=0;
        }

       else if ( nu == 0 )
        {
          display=1;
        }

       if ()
        {
          print "Title: " title;
          print "Subtitle: " subtitle;
          print "Keywords: " keywords;
          print "uaggr: " praggr(uaggr);
          print "kaggr: " praggr(kaggr);
          print "nu:" nu;
          print "nk:" nk;
        }
       next
     }
     $0 ~ end_ere { display=0 ; print "" }
     display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
}
```

And with process substitution you can use something like this:

```bash
<(echo 'function praggr (aggr) {
       resultstr = ""
       for (k in aggr) resultstr = (resultstr " | " aggr[k])
       return resultstr
     }
')
```

Or to avoid problems with single quotes `'` you can use `cat << EOF`:

```bash
<(cat <<'EOF' 
function praggr (aggr) {
  resultstr = ""
  for (k in aggr) resultstr = (resultstr " | " aggr[k])
    return resultstr
}
EOF
)
```

Finally, your `awk` command would become:

```bash
awk -v yourvars... -f <(echo 'function praggr (aggr) {
       resultstr = ""
       for (k in aggr) resultstr = (resultstr " | " aggr[k])
       return resultstr
     }
') -f test.awk "$filename"
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding.  I want to call functions that are defined in an `awk` file rather than defining things in the `bash` script.

Comment: @Avacha I'm confused now, I see you edited the question and added that you want to add some code `in an awk function`  and you also want to call the functions defined in an `awk` file. So why don't you use `awk -f` for that? You can create a file `functions.awk` where you define all your functions and also create the main file called `main.awk` where you call your functions. Something like this: `awk -v yourvars... -f functions.awk -f main.awk`. Is not that what you want?

Comment: So I would need both a functions awk file and a main awk file?

Comment: If you want to have the functions and the main code in different files, then yes, you would. AFAIK you cannot use `awk -f main.awk '{ code }'` so in this case you have to use `-f` option to define several `awk` scripts. My suggestion about *process substitution* is for avoid creating a file (either the `main.awk` or `functions.awk`).

Comment: So continue defining everything in quotes?  As my `awk` code got is getting longer and longer (with the additional problem that in a bash script, the `awk` code does not get properly syntax highlighted), I decided to put things in an actual `awk` file. What would one put in `main.awk`?

Comment: @Avacha Well, since I thought the you awk code was actually that then the process substitution could be useful, but given your case than it should not be the best.  Regarding `I decided to put things in an actual awk file`, then why don't you add all your code in your awk file? Without using the `main.awk` obviously.

Comment: Regarding the question: `Could I put $0 ~ beg_ere { etc in an awk function?`. The answer is yes, you can add that code to a function in the same way yo create the `praggr` function.

Comment: I would need to have a main `awk` file that I can call from a bash script.  How can I do that?

Comment: Regarding "I don't think it's possible to specify awk -f and awk '{code...}' simultaneously" - see GNU awk's `-e` option and `AWKPATH` may also be relevant. The OP appears to already be using GNU awk for `gensub()`.

Comment: @Avacha to execute from bash (or shell script) you have to add (in the first line) the shebang to the awk script (`#! /usr/bin/awk -f`) and with bash you have to set it execution permissions to file and running it like this: `./main.awk filetoread`.

Comment: @EdMorton oh, that's true!! Thanks! That's so useful (I forgot to check the `--help`). About`AWKPATH`, is this also a GNUism? or that environment variable can be used in other awks?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon you're welcome. Yes, `AWKPATH` is also a GNUism, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#AWKPATH-Variable

Comment: @EdMorton nice, that's great. I appreciate it :).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file with `.awk` extension, for example `script.awk`, and paste the awk expression in this file. Then, you can reference the file in the command.

```bash
awk -v ukeys="$keyw" -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v pn_ere="$pn_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere" -f script.awk "$filename"
```

Comment: Could I put `$0 ~ beg_ere {` etc in an `awk` function?